# creating liquid synthaxx app

Tags: admin, shopify

I'm a new developer to Shopify but been developing websites for 10+ years. Just got my partner account and private application setup. Been looking through the available documentations on the site and wasn't sure if applications are allowed to live on the users' shopify site or admin. is this possible? All I've seen so far are api call documentations but I'm having no luck finding anything regarding, how to add options to the admin or the liquid theme. Any references or pointers would be great!

I'm trying to figure out a way so when a user installs my app, A can add a 'part' that they can use and even new variables that they can use.

Answer (score 0):

Try building with Greasemonkey for Firefox or a native Chrome App. Then convince your clients to install your code in their shop admin. Partner App with Shopify lets you inject links too. Hook that all up to your backend, and you're golden.

Comment: Thanks and while this sounds like a solution I'm trying to work on an app for shopify and not building it for a specific client.

Comment: Right... well, this applies. Shopify made an exception for one App to use Chrome and overlay code in the admin, so maybe they'll do same for you. Either way, you cannot change the admin yourself, you'll have to use your own Javascript and get the clients to allow it.

Also, you can always inject your own Liquid scripts too. And edit existing ones.